# javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex is my weak skills.
How to check by regex following strings:

```
http://www.facebook.com/johnsmith
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000111111111
http://www.facebook.com/people/John-Smith/100000111111111
```

so, only similar strings should be valid, rest are invalid. How to do it?

Comment: what do you mean by similar  strings?

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT

I think I see what you mean.

```
var url = "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000111111111";
(/^http:[/][/]www[.]facebook[.]com[/]((profile[.]php[?]id=[0-9]{15}|people).*$|[A-za-z]*$)/).test(url);
```

would something like that work?

Comment: thank you. But it says that string http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1XXX is correct. How to fix

Comment: @user285336 isn't it supposed to? I'll amend it... is the id always of the format 100000111111111?

Comment: I mean if I enter http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=1USER your regex says that I enter correct string

Answer (score 0):

Start with a [simple tutorial](http://www.icewarp.com/support/online_help/203030104.htm) and use [an online tester](http://regexpal.com/) to ensure you get the regex correct. Once you've got the basics, refer to this [cheatsheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/) to try new features.

You may need to be much more specific in what you do and don't want to match. For example, asking to match `http://www.facebook.com/johnsmith` suggests that the user's name consists of letters, but are numbers and symbols valid?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var matchUserLink = function(name, id, s) {
  var baseUrl = 'http://www.facebook.com/';
  s = "" + s;
  return (s == (baseUrl + name.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, ''))) ||
    (s == (baseUrl + 'profile.php?id=' + id)) ||
    (s == (baseUrl + 'people/' + name.replace(/\W/g, '-') + '/' + id));
};

var js='John Smith', id=101, fb='http://www.facebook.com/';
matchUserLink(js, id, fb+'johnsmith'); // => true
matchUserLink(js, id, fb+'profile.php?id=101'); // => true
matchUserLink(js, id, fb+'people/John-Smith/101'); // => true
```